# How to join two elasticsearch inserts?

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins, kibana

I am very new to elasticsearch and come from a SQL background. We are trying to use a ELK stack to monitor a Jenkins server. We use the elasticsearch report plugin to send a bunch of information about the job. However, we also have some custom information that we would need to send. However, how can I join these two pieces of information in Kibana? In a SQL database, I would have two tables, then join them based on a key. However, I don't how to do it in elasticsearch. Any suggestions?

Comment: One extra thing, the first insert will be done by the Jenkins pipeline (i.e. our code), but the second insert will be done by the elasticsearch reporter which we have no control of, so update may be out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, join is the strong-suite of relational DBs (aka SQL DBs) and the weak-spot of the NoSQL (Elasticsearch among them). Having said that, ES does support such operations and if performance is not critical, you can try it: [Elasticsearch joining queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html). In a nutshell:

1. Create a [join-field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html). This is the equivalent for a foreign key constraint in SQL. Since you have control over the logstash part, I suggest you make it the parent and the ES report info the child.
2. Use the [has_child query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) when you query the logs. This type of query acts like the join query in SQL.